# How to reveal text line by line - Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a simple app, I have a button that when pressed will display separate lines of text on the screen. I set an int = 0 and use an if statement that will add 1 at each line. The issue I have is that all lines are displayed after 1 button press, I want 1 button press one line displayed, next button press next line displayed and so on:

```
int nmbr = 0;
int myInt1 = [textfield.text intValue];

if (nmbr == 0) {
  tString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"111111111111%i x 1 = %i",myInt1,myInt1];
  nmbr++;
}

if (nmbr == 1){
  tString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"222222222222%i x 2 = %i",myInt1,myInt1*2];
  nmbr++;
}

if (nmbr == 2){
  tString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i x 3 = %i",myInt1,myInt1*3];
  nmbr++;
}
```

I am new to this so any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Update:
Thanks folks for your help so far, I am not sure that I have explained this issue well……possibly gone about programming it all wrong. I have only one button on screen and each time it is pressed it would change a blank label to a text string. I was incrementing in each if statement so that on the next button press as nmbr  = 2 then text label 2 would be modified, press again nmbr = 3 text label 3 would be modified and so on. There appears to be no separation in the code so on the button press all text labels are modified. I am not sure if it is possible to code multiple actions on a single button or if there is a better way to do this.

I have tried else if statements but still no joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is normal because you if test are coming one after each other. The program will go on the first if, incremented nmbr, go out of the if and hit the next if.

It can work by moving the nmbr incrementation out of the "if" (as mentioned by mydogisbox) but you will still have to declare the variable as static. 
Something like this:

```
static int nmbr = 0;
int myInt1 = [textfield.text intValue];

if (nmbr == 0) {
  tString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"111111111111%i x 1 = %i",myInt1,myInt1];
}

if (nmbr == 1){
  tString1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"222222222222%i x 2 = %i",myInt1,myInt1*2];
}

if (nmbr == 2){
  tString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i x 3 = %i",myInt1,myInt1*3];
  nmbr = 0; // if you have no other lines and you want to start from begining when the user press the button more than 3 times.
}

nmbr++;
```

Answer (score 2):

Move your `nmbr++;` to the end of the method instead of putting it in each `if` statement.  If you don't want it to increment every time then use a bool to keep track of whether or not you want to increment it.  Also, `nmbr` needs to be a member variable (i.e. class level) instead of method level.  If it is method level then its state isn't saved between calls.

Answer (score 0):

Create required number of buttons in Interface Builder, declare them into `.h` file, create methods for each button `-(void)firstButtonClick:(UIButton)sender`, `-(void)secondButtonClick:(UIButton)sender` and put your code into these methods.

Comment: I think you misunderstand his problem.  He wants to use one button multiple times, but right now `nmbr` increments in every `if` so all `if`s execute every time the method fires.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're incrementing within the if and then letting it fall to the next.  Look at the flow: nmbr is one, so execute that block, which increments nmber to 1, making the next block true also.  Depending on your style guides or personal preferences, you could:

1. Change the later `if`s to `else if`.
2. Move all the `nmbr++`s to after the last `if`.
3. Return after incrementing inside the `if`.